# Establish trust between Samba 3 and AD using Windows 2012 R2 DC

Tags: samba

Unable to establish trust between Samba 3 and Windows 2012 R2 AD. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not having the reputation to comment I'm answering instead.  What is it you're trying to do?

I've found [PBIS](http://www.beyondtrust.com/Products/PowerBrokerIdentityServicesADBridge/) the easiest way to get a Ubuntu box onto a Windows domain (2012 R2 in my case).  When setting up a file server I then used the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/samba-ad-integration.html) to setup the Samba shares.

Comment: We are doing a migration from OpenLDAP to AD. We have to retain a few file servers that are running Samba. We need to setup trust between Samba and AD domain so we don't authenticate twice. At the moment when we try to establish trust it fails.